# why is java binary in two locations in the JDK?

Tags: java

On Windows I noticed that the java binary is in two different locations (I have the JDK installed):

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java.exe
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\bin\java.exe
```

Similarly on a Unix box that I have access to, there are two copies, one in jre/bin and one just in bin. I am not sure if this other one is the JDK or just a JRE installation.

In both cases, they are the same size as each other. I confirmed they aren't symlinked on the Linux side although I suppose they could be hard linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contents of jdk/bin/ is the Java binaries that are included with the Java Developers Kit. The Java binaries inside of jdk/jre/bin are the Java Runtime Environment's binaries.

If you have the JDK version of Java then use the one in jdk/bin/.

**But they are the same**

If you look at the executables there is actually no difference in them, so it really doesn't matter.

```
$ pwd
/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_45

$ ll jre/bin/java
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 7718 Oct  8  2013 jre/bin/java
[saml@greeneggs jdk1.7.0_45]$ ls -l bin/java
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 7718 Oct  8  2013 bin/java

$ cmp jre/bin/java bin/java
$
```